# How do I set up an ASP.NET Web Forms application to use Ninject.Web 3.0.0 RC3?

Tags: ninject, ninject.web

I am trying to set up my ASP.NET Web Forms (Framework 4.0) application to use Ninject.Web. I would like to use RC3 of Ninject 3.0.0, since I ran into issues with databound controls.

Through my inspections of Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web, it seems that there are two ways to create a kernel using the existing framework. The first way is through the class defined in the App_Start folder, and the second is through overriding the CreateKernel method when deriving from NinjectHttpApplication.

Going forward with Ninject.Web 3.0.0, which method is preferred for creating a kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no prefered way. The App_Start way was added for NuGet, so that it doesn't need to change an existing file. NinjectHttpApplication was kept for backwards compatibility. Use which ever you like more.

Comment: I suppose the point though is that the two methods are mutually exclusive. I should use one or the other but not both, correct?